# CSS right negative margins

Tags: css, overflow, margin

please help me to solve a little problem with css margins.

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body {
    background-image: url('/images/pat_1.gif'); 
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#wrapper {  
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 960px;
}
#content {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 -50px;
}
```

Inside `#content` there is a lot of divs with `width: 960px;`. I'm writing here negative margins cause I need a white space (`background-color: #fff;`) on both sides of my `#wrapper`. And everything is Ok, until I resize browsers' window to 960px - the main problem is that right negative margin doesn't disappear for the window border, it doesn't become hidden like a left margin.

I aready tried `overflow: hidden`, but it doesn't help.

Thanks for your suggests

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
Copy paste this line to `<head>`. This will load a css file only if the user has a screen ressolution that meets your setup.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/q900.css" media="only screen and (min-width : 640px) and (max-width: 999px)" />
```

Comment: It looks great, thanks for your advice, but if there is some more simple method to solve this problem, without including another css file? And if I will follow your advice does this css file loads when resolution more than 999px or less then 640px?

Comment: the css will load when the user has a screen between 640px and 999px. Yes there is a easy way to solve it, but I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve.